# Scaffold/Scaffolding

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, difference

Can both scaffold and scaffolding be used about the scaffold/scaffolding as a whole an not just the platforms? And the same with the platforms? I'm only interested in the American definition of it.

He climbed up the scaffold/scaffolding.

Afraid to fall down, the man lay flat on the scaffold/scaffolding, holding onto it with everything he'd got.

Comment: Have you used a dictionary? Which one?

Answer (score 1):

"Scaffold" seems like a single discrete structure, a *thing*. "Scaffolding" is more like a mass noun, so it brings to mind *stuff*.

I might rent [a scaffold](https://www.homedepot.com/p/MetalTech-Safeclimb-6-ft-x-6-ft-x-2-1-2-ft-Baker-Style-Scaffold-1100-lbs-Capacity-I-CISCH1/302038304) to paint my house, but Notre Dame is currently [covered in scaffolding](https://www.architecturaldigest.com/story/where-paris-notre-dame-cathedral-stands-one-year-after-fire).